# How to make sure that two logic and comparison operations are equal?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

I see a logical and comparison operation in the code and I feel like it can be simplified.

Simply put, it looks like:

```
if (!a || !(b || c)) {...}
```

But I think it's the same as

```
if (!a || !b || !c) {...}
```

How should I do in this situation? I suppose I can see more operations like this in existing code I have to deal with. Are there rules to simplify/optimize such operation aside from manual checking?

Comment: Interesting link: [De Morgans law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws  Your transformation should have introduced an `&&` somewhere: "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)".

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [DeMorgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to get:

```
if (!a || (!b && !c)) {...}
```

Which, because of `&&` having higher precedence than `||`, is the same as:

```
if (!a || !b && !c) {...}
```

However that whole conditions seems very negative, and it is almost always easier to read positive conditions, perhaps it would be better written as:

```
// This is the negation of your condition after applying DeMorgan's law
if ( a && (b || c) ) {
    // return or throw error
}

... // What you would've done in the if statement
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is if !(b || c) us the same as !b || !c.
Try a simple truth table:

```
b   c  !(b||c)  !b||!c
0   0    1         1
0   1    0         1
1   0    0         1
1   1    0         0
```

So they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

As a general technique for approaching this type of boolean refactoring, if you don't trust your own ability to construct truth tables, how about writing some code along these lines:

```
for a in {true, false}
  for b in {true, false}
    for c in {true, false}
      if (!a || !(b || c)) <> (!a || !b || !c)
      then exit with message "Not equivalent"
    end
  end
end
```

The `if` condition can of course be replaced with whatever two expressions you are trying to test.